# xpath to find a first child node with particular attribute, for any number of child nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

```
    <Names>
        <Name type="M">John</Name>
        <Name type="F">Susan</Name>
        <Name type="M">David</Name>
        <Name type="M"></Name>
    </Names>
```

For this input xml i want to read only the first node with attribute M. One can write `XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name[@type='M']");`
But it will return values of all the attributes with value M.

I tried something like

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name[@type='M'][1]");
```

But its not working.

Comment: Please specify "not working". What result do you get, and how does that differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SelectSingleNode()`, since you are trying to select only one node

```
xml.SelectSingleNode("/Names/Name[@type='M'][1]");
```